# Listview - changing the backgrond color of an item

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to have the background color of rows the user already clicked in a listview changed, to do this I'm using an arraylist saved in SharedPreferences contining the ids of the clicked rows, the problem is that the color changes almost randomly.

code:

```
    private static class ItemHolder {
        public TextView TXTTitle, TXTArtist, TXTid, TXTLikes;
        public RelativeLayout back;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup root) {
        ItemHolder holder = new ItemHolder();

        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, root, false);

            RelativeLayout _back = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.bg_item);

            holder.back = _back;

            // paint oldies
            Set<String> _set = new HashSet<String>();
            _set = Prefs.getStringSet("arrOfOldies", _set);
            for(int i = 0; i <= _set.size()  ; i++){
                if(_set.contains(IDs.get(position))){
                //oldie
                            holder.back.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D0D0D0"));
                    }
            }

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
                holder = (ItemHolder) view.getTag();       
        }
    }
```

I think it has something to do with the way a listview is being built, what's the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: How do you handle the `holder` ? Please post above code. The whole `Adapter` would be great ;)

Comment: the whole thing is huge so I added more of it

Comment: Check this one [GOOD LISTVIEW TUTORIAL](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) focus on holder patern so you dont need save selections in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add to  Manitoba's answer,  you also have to reset the background if the item has never been selected. 
Understand that the point of using a convertView and an item holder is reusing views for optimisation. If you reuse a view from an item that has been selected for an item that's never been : the background color will still be here.

try :

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup root)
{
    ItemHolder holder = null;

    if (view == null)
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, root, false);
        holder = new ItemHolder();

        holder.back = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.bg_item);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ItemHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    // paint oldies
    Set<String> _set = new HashSet<String>();
    _set = Prefs.getStringSet("arrOfOldies", _set);
    for(int i = 0; i <= _set.size()  ; i++)
    {
        if(_set.contains(IDs.get(position)))
        {
            holder.back.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D0D0D0"));
        }
        else 
        {
            //add this else clause.
            holder.back.setBackgroundColor( YOUR_DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_COLOR ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made a small mistake, move the `background`part after you've retrieve the existing holder.
Here is the clean code to use.

```
private static class ItemHolder
{
    public TextView TXTTitle, TXTArtist, TXTid, TXTLikes;
    public RelativeLayout back;

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup root)
    {
        ItemHolder holder = null;

        if (view == null)
        {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, root, false);
            holder = new ItemHolder();

            holder.back = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.bg_item);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ItemHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        // paint oldies
        Set<String> _set = new HashSet<String>();
        _set = Prefs.getStringSet("arrOfOldies", _set);
        if(_set.contains(IDs.get(position)))
        {
            //oldie
            holder.back.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#D0D0D0"));
        }else{
            holder.back.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but the backgroung keeps changing randomly, it starts in the right way but changes when I scroll

Comment: Still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong. You are not taking recycling ListViews into consideration in your code. Also, You do not need need to check if the _set contains your item AS MANY TIMES AS THERE ARE OBJECTS IN YOUR SET. You should refactor your code to reflect these points:

- Your biggest problem is that you are NEVER setting you **holper** variable unless your view is null, and it is only null as many times as there are list items that fit on your screen at the same time - when they get recycled, your color gets weird. Fix this, and it will get resolved. Here is some [ListView recycling info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)
- Move your _set out of the getView function
- get rid of for loop iterating the values of your _set